# Knockout js built-in variable ($data)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know that **$data** variable provides access to the current object your context is in.
Also I can use foreach binding and add property name to the books object.

---

This code iterate over the array named **books** and result are displayed in the DOM as list of items.

> But why if I change that array name from books to any other name it does not display items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data Binding with KnockoutJS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul >
    <!-- ko foreach: books -->
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
    <script>
        var ViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;

            self.books = [
                'Journy to the earth',
                'effective study plans'

            ];
        };
        var myModel = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(myModel);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code after changing array name to **titles** and cause error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data Binding with KnockoutJS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul >
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
    <script>
        var ViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;

            self.titles= [
                'Journy to the earth',
                'effective study plans'

            ];
        };
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the code that does not work.

Comment: @Salketer added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you omitted the foreach part when changing the variable name:

```
<ul >
<!-- ko foreach: books -->
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

You changed to

```
<ul >
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

But should have changed to

```
<ul >
<!-- ko foreach: titles -->
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Notice that I changed the foreach instruction to use the new variable name.

Comment: thanks @salketer. I thought it is just comment and have no effect on the code excution.

Comment: THey are indeed "just" html comments, but they are used by knockout.

Comment: where can I find how these comments are manipulated by knockout ?

Comment: see the start of the instruction with "ko" and ends with "/ko"